# Unable to sign VBA with valid Sectigo Code Signing certificate - but signing .msi works fine

Tags: excel, vba, certificate, signing

I bumped into the same issue as this topic: [Unable to sign VBA with valid Sectigo Code Signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273647/unable-to-sign-vba-with-valid-sectigo-code-signing-certificate)
Basically, I have a Sectigo EV code signing certificate with a USB-stick that I need to plug in in order to sign my code. I am using that for signing my excel add-in in Visual Studio (DLLs) and the .msi file that we build from that with signtool:

> signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /d Prog2Installer.msi /a C:\Users\hello\source\repos\ME\Prog2\bin\Release\Prog2mInstaller.msi

That works fine, I get a pop-up asking me for my password and it signs ok.

But now I also want to use my certificate to sign my excel/VBA xlsm file. When I plug in my USB key I can select the certificate in VBE (named "Installed by Sectigo Browser extension"), but when I save the file, I get the same feedback as the referenced post:

> There is a problem with the digital certificate. The VBA project could not be signed. The signature will be cancelled

I checked the certmgr, can see the certificate there, but can't export as .pfx, only as .cer (so no private keys, as they reside on the USB stick I assume). I also added those 3 timestamp items that were suggested in the referenced post, but still nothing.

Sectigo/Comodo seem to have no clue (tried their helpdesks), I hope that anyone here can advice me what to do to get this to work?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Have spent hours in the last few days with Sectigo support - including sharing the screen with them and demonstrating the problem. They've given up and have suggested I contact Microsoft. I still have 5 days left on my old certificate, but need to get back the old version of SafeNet (it was from 3 years ago) I had as well (as the new certificate needs the newer version I'd updated SafeNet). If that still works then that should rule out a problem with Office and it's likely to be something to do with the certificate and/or Safenet software.

Comment: I got hold of an old version of SafeNet and was able to sign VBA code with my old (nearly expired) token. Therefore the problem is with the token and/or SafeNet and not some change in Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a response from Sectigo - who had contacted the certificate token manufacturer. It looks like this is indeed Microsoft's problem - requiring an MD5 hash when signing VBA code - even though that's no longer considered secure.

As a workaround, if you are using Safenet AND if your token still supports MD5, you can make the following registry changes:

1. Find the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC"
2. Add a new registry key "Crypto"
3. Add a new string value to this key - "Disable-Crypto"
4. Give "Disable-Crypto" a value "None"

Then, add the signature to VBA in the usual way. In my case, when saving the file, it asks for the token password three times before completing the save.

[Full details - inluding more information about the issue](https://www.certisur.com/en/technical-communication-safenet-gemalto/)

Unless there is a change to the MD5 requirement for signing VBA code, it will not be possible to sign VBA code at all in the future (i.e. no certificate providers will support it). Therefore, I suggest that people contact Microsoft to urge them to act on this issue.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but this sounds like a working answer to me. So basically MSFT is using an outdated hashing algorithm to sign its VBA projects... Will try to file an issue with MSFT, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had some phone conversations with their helpdesk. My summary of those conversations: it's Microsofts problem... I didn't file anything with MSFT but as I needed a working certificate, I went for the EV code signing for my DLL/Visual studio (works fine) and bought a simple code signing certificate to sign my VBA/Excel. After a bit of fiddling it simply works. So I pay 580 USD/year vs 400 USD/year but have a working solution.

So I'm a Schrodinger Sectigo customer now, being both happy & unhappy at the same time.

Comment: I've just been in contact with GlobalSign - they say they are also having a similar problem with their certificates and are working on a fix.

Comment: So then it's probably an issue of the party that makes the software to interact with the USB-key, I assume it's not them but a third party.

Comment: The issue is actually Microsoft's - see my answer.