# Signing VBA Code in Excel XLSM files - There was a problem with the Digital Certificate

Tags: excel, vba, ssl, ms-office, code-signing

I have a DigiCert EV Code Signing certificate to sign my c# code, and it works great.

However, now I'm trying to sign VBA code in an Excel XLSM file.

I get the error "There was a problem with the Digital Certificate. The VBA Project could not be signed. The signature will be discarded."

DigiCert support does not seem to be able to find a solution.

I have tried saving the VBA project first, then saving the file, as discussed here...
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07f0158c-085b-4031-93a1-c9d047cf855c/unable-to-sign-outlook-2010-vbaproject?forum=outlook

I have an EV Code Signing Certificate, so I cannot export the file with the certificate path  as discussed here...
https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO1451.html
and here...
[Unable to sign VBA with valid Sectigo Code Signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273647/unable-to-sign-vba-with-valid-sectigo-code-signing-certificate)

I thought maybe it's b/c I have an EV certificate and I may actually need a PFX certificate instead, but DigiCert said the following...

> By November (or sooner) it also won't be possible with standard code signing.  the reason it won't be possible is that standards require "qualified" hardware to store the private key and the code signing certificate, and that hardware by default makes it "read-only" or more specifically make it so that you may use it but may not export it.

So I'm hoping someone here has an answer to this. Microsoft just released some update to office that will block VBA without a bunch of extra steps unless the code is signed...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/security/internet-macros-blocked

Any help here is greatly appreciated...

Comment: What code do you use for signing vba macros? Or commands if you do that manually?

Comment: in the vba window, under tools --> digital signature

Comment: We find ourselves in the exact same situation, since May this year (2022) when we renewed our EV Code Signing certificate. Ever since we renewed and started using the new USB token, the problem appeared. Beforehand (previous two renewals) it was working fine - instead of the dreaded "There was a problem with the Digital Certificate. The VBA Project could not be signed. The signature will be discarded." error we would get a popup window from "SafeNet Authentication Client" asking us to input the token password. If the correct password was provided, the VBA Editor would sign and save the project

Comment: P.S. After the issue first appeared in May this year (2022), when renewing with the provider we had been successfully using during the previous two years (Sectigo), we have since (this September) purchased a new EV Code Signing certificate from DigiCert. Unfortunately, the behavior is exactly the same. I have a suspicion that the issue may NOT be with the CA (Sectigo/DigiCert), but rather with the manufacturer/supplier they both use for the USB hardware tokens - it used to be "Gemalto" before May this year (when VBA signing worked) and now it is "Thales".

Comment: P.S. #2 The change in USB hardware token manufacturer/supplier can also be seen in the branding of the "SafeNet Authentication Client" software - it used to be "Gemalto" in earlier versions, while it now reads "Thales". In the next few days, I will log our issues and findings with DigiCert technical support, asking them to investigate further and raise this with Thales, if necessary. I will share any progress and hopefully a successful resolution here.

Comment: @YasenSimeonov -- This is fascinating. I hadn't thought about the token change, but I think you are on to something. I'm now getting sent to the 3rd separate support team with Microsoft to try and resolve this after running out of runway with Digicert, but I had not thought of the token client software. I also did notice this issue and one of the solutions that Digicert offered was to use the OLD client which was "Gemalto" however the old client does not support the NEW keys with stronger security. So this is making a lot of sense...

Comment: @YasenSimeonov -- Thinking through your comments, I went to Thales' website (https://gemalto.service-now.com/csm?id=kb_article_view&sys_kb_id=36211dc047e68d10128dca72e36d43a0&sysparm_article=KB0025687) and I see that they released `SafeNet Minidriver 10.8 R6 (Post GA) (2)` which says this --> `Improvements in Microsoft Certificate renewal failing with SAC 10.7. Fo details, refer to "Resolved Issues" in the CRN.`

Comment: @YasenSimeonov -- the install version found on that page is `10.8.2169.0` and the one i got from digicert was `10.8.2154.0` so i'm installing now to see if this fixes...

Comment: I have been active in the Microsoft TechNet Forums thread you pointed to in your OP (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/difficulties-signing-the-vba-project-code/m-p/1641514) and it turns out it is a compatibility issue between the USB hardware token and the (latest) version of Thales' SafeNet Authentication Client software and its supporting drivers. The solution so far has been to rollback to a very old version, which I am unwilling to do. Will contact DigiCert support to: a. ask them to verify and provide a more recent version of the SafeNet client, which does work with...

Comment: ...signing Excel VBA projects and b. raise this issue with Thales, hopefully leading to this being fixed in future/newer versions of the SafeNet Authentication Client software & drivers.

Comment: i escalated this at digicert, but they seem unwilling to bring this up to thales. of course, i am not a thales customer and their system is setup to only support existing OEM type customers, not individual users. so i'm trying to get digicert to revisit, thus far with no luck whatsoever. i tried installing the updated driver above but it requires some sort of challenge/response code for my token and nobody at digicert seems to know what that is for. presumably it is something they do on their end before they send these things out.

Comment: also, i got the same advice to roll back to an older version of the driver, but that doesn't work with the latest ev code signing certs b/c the old driver version doesn't support the latest 4096-bit encryption... so i'm kindof back to square one. also, i raised a case with microsoft and they did nothing but trade me around to 4 different support teams and i'm still not anywhere at all...

Comment: @gotmike -- I managed to solve the issue with the help of DigiCert support. See my post/solution below, hope it works for you too.

Comment: Just got bitten by the same. Outlook will not accept any certificate anymore, neither 'official' with the private key read-protected on a smartcard (should ask for a pin code, gives an error instead), nor self signed (generated by Offce selfsign.exe).
 The only way I found to run a macro at all in Outlook was to disable macro security entirely, which does not sound like "better security"  to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is a change in the default behavior of the SafeNet Authentication Client software, starting with version 10.5. A list of obsolete/deprecated cryptographic algorithms (including the one needed for Office/Excel VBA signing) get disabled by default. For more details see the original KB article on Thales' website [here](https://supportportal.thalesgroup.com/csm?sys_kb_id=5d7a3b8bdb25b050f0e3220805961944&id=kb_article_view&sysparm_rank=3&sysparm_tsqueryId=78c769d2c3c78d105626176ce0013139&sysparm_article=KB0024651) (thanks to DigiCert support for providing this).

I have found two solutions:

1. Uninstall your current (v10.5 or newer) version of the SafeNet Authentication Client. Then download and install version 10.4 (or any older version) from [here](https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-installation/safenet-drivers).
2. As @vzczc alluded to earlier, if we are to use version 10.5+, then we need to manually import/create a specific Registry Key and Value. Here is how I did it in more detail:

- I was using SafeNet Authentication Client version 10.8 R6, build 10.8.2154.0 to start with:
  [image: SAC Version]
- First thing I did was right click on the "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" icon in the tray and choose "Eject Token JC". Then I physically unplugged the USB token from my PC:
  [image: Eject Token]
- Again in your Windows tray, right click on the SAC icon and choose "Exit".
- Open Windows Task Manager (`Ctrl + Shift + Esc` keyboard shortcut), go to the "Details" tab. Right-click -> End Task any leftover process whose name begins with "SAC..." (I had one of these running even after exiting SAC from the tray!):
  [image: Task Manager]
- Open the Registry Editor (`WinKey + R` keyboard shortcut, then `regedit`). Navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC` key, right-click on "SAC" and choose New -> Key. Name the new key `Crypto`
  [image: Regedit New key]
- Now right-click the new `Crypto` key we just created and choose New -> String Value. Name the new value `Disable-Crypto`
  [image: regedit New String Value]
- In the right pane, double-click on the new `Disable-Crypto` value that we just created. In the resulting dialog box, set the "Value data" property to `None` and hit OK
  [image: regedit set value]
- If everything went right, your final Registry structure should look like this:
  [image: regedit final result]
- Now Restart your PC.
- After the restart, wait for all your programs (incl. SafeNet Authentication Client) to load up again. Once you see the SAC icon in the tray, plug the hardware token into your PC's USB port again.
- You should now be able to sign and save Excel VBA projects.

Comment: Thank you.   Worked for me.  Would have been very hard to find.

Comment: This answer saved me today. All new code signing certificates have to be issued with a token now (https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/code-signing-changes-in-2023) and cannot export the PFX file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue with a certificate from GlobalSign. After searching for a solution and talking to support at both Microsoft and Global Sign, I found a solution that resolved the issue for me.

In the registry, add the following key (Crypto) here:

HKLM\Software\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC

Add a string to this key named Disable-Crypto, with value "None"

Source:
https://www.certisur.com/en/technical-communication-safenet-gemalto/

I then had to reboot to enable this.

Comment: i tried this and no luck for me... is it still working for you?

Comment: Yes, this still works fine for me.

Comment: @gotmike - unplugging the USB token from my PC and exiting SAC from the tray before making changes to the registry made a difference for me. Also, make sure to restart your PC after creating the appropriate registry key & value. Plug the USB token back in only after your PC has restarted. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: after reviewing @YasenSimeonov solution, i think i misread your answer about adding the `Crypto` key first... but i also had to use the other steps as well...

Answer (score 0):

Another step may be needed after regedit. I was prompted for my token password in an endless loop (and after three tries the device is locked). Went into SafeNet Tools, Advanced, and set Single Sign on.

Then I signed an executable with signtool, which prompted for the password only once, and worked OK.

Then in Excel it does not prompt for a password and saved the xla fine.

Answer (score -1):

When the macro is signed with the Excel VBA menu command, it tries to use a very weak signing algorithm in the code signing so many modern signing utilities refuse to use it.

But the good news is that it is possible to use strong algorithms to sign Excel macros by using the signtool.exe that comes with Visual Studio.

You also need the "officesips" tools from microsoft from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617

The installation procedure is a bit crude. You need to extract the files and then use the readme.txt to do the manual steps.

After this, the signtool can be used similarly as for .exe and .dll files. For example:

```
signtool sign /fd sha256 /sha1 your-cert-thumbprint /td SHA384 /tr "http://timestamp.digicert.com/" TheExcelMacroFile.xla

Done Adding Additional Store

Successfully signed: TheExcelMacroFile.xla
```

The source of this  information was from here:

https://docs.digicert.com/en/software-trust-manager/signing-tools/excel-macro-signing-with-signtool.html

Comment: Already covered by this answer, right? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75021697/